# Where do i find maps of internet access around the world?

Tags: networking, connection, global

I work for a group of large NGOs (Non Government Organizations) engaged in humanitarian work through out the world. Often internet access is an issue and having access to reliable data on availability, capacity and quality data on internet access in the developing world would be of GREAT value.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to relate to computer hardware or software, and is thus off-topic for SuperUser. I can't really think of any StackExchange site where it would be on topic, either.

Comment: is something like [this](http://www.netindex.com/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Finding a library (or a web interface to) that accumulates some kind of information is not a software related question? I think this is a great question! Those maps are certainly a cool to look at.  Or even use as a "live" wallpaper! That's ubersuperuser!

Comment: Yes, Karthik, that link is a GREAT start and in highly ranked countries where there's ample information very useful *local* data is also available. Thank you! In the countries where NGOs are operating it would also be great to see the *edge* of the network and locations where access is not available and thus can get ISPs/MNOs/Satellite providers involved to extend access where needed.

Comment: u can probably do something from number of ppl per country that submitted, and in africa i see a band of countries with no submissions, but i doubt more detailed information is possible without sourcing from the ISPs themselves

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Please refer to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) for information about what questions are on topic here on SuperUser. Specifically, "software" refers to software running on a personal computer (as opposed to, say, a server or a mobile device). This question is about research into network infrastructure.